# Fix needed for SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog to work with Edge and Chrome

Tags: sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog

Anyone know of the fix to make this work in Chrome and Edge?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
       SelectEmployee();
     });
  
    function SelectEmployee()
     {
       var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
          options.url = "/sites/Team/Lists/Personnel/NewMemberSelect.aspx";
   options.dialogReturnValueCallback = RefreshOnDialogClose;
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResults.Cancel);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript libraries that contain the implementation of the modal dialogs may not have been loaded at the time the jQuery ready function is executed. You can call `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to tell SharePoint to wait until these libraries have been loaded and then call `SelectEmployee`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SelectEmployee, "sp.js");
    });

    function SelectEmployee() {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        options.url = "/sites/demo3/Lists/ShowModalDialogTest/NewForm.aspx";
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = RefreshOnDialogClose;
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResults.Cancel);
    }

</script>
```